# Importing Commerce Variants from google sheet

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2, plugin-feedme

How I should set up google sheet data to import Commerce Variants from it?
It is necessary that the Variants are imported in the same way as [this example](https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/guides/importing-commerce-variants.html#setup-your-feed).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check the tip in [this page](https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/feature-tour/creating-your-feed.html)

> TIP
>
> When using Google Sheet as your feed type, consult the Google Sheets API docs. Your URL should include a key value for your API key. For example:
>
> https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/*SHEET_NUMBER*/values/SheetName?key=*API_KEY*